# jquery - dynamic element not being created

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add another `<a>` element after `<a id='link1'>`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var myHTML = "<div id='test'>";
                myHTML += "<span><a id='link1'>link 1</a></span>";
                $("a#link1").after("<a id='link2'>link 2</a>");
                myHTML += "</div>";
                $("div#insertHere").html(myHTML);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="insertHere">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The output of the above should be**

```
<body>
   <div id="insertHere">
      <div id="test">
         <span>
            <a id="link1">link 1</a>
            <a id="link2">link 2</a>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to query elements you haven't added to the DOM yet.
When you do `$("a#link1")` it does not retrieve any element because the HTML you "generated" before is not in the DOM yet, it's still just text in your variable `myHTML`.

Generate all the markup and apply it at once:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myHTML = "<div id='test'>";
    myHTML += "<a id='link1'>link 1</a>";
    myHTML += "<a id='link2'>link 2</a>";
    myHTML += "</div>";
    $("div#insertHere").html(myHTML);
});
```

If you need to bind events (or else) to the elements you are adding, you can use the dom manipualtion API from jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $div = $('<div id="test">').addClass('myClass');

    $('<a id="link1">link 1</a>').click(function() { }).appendTo($div);
    $('<a id="link2">link 2</a>').appendTo($div);

    $("div#insertHere").append($div);
});
```

Further reading:

- [jQuery - Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Answer (score 1):

In your markup `insertHere` div is empty I don't see any existing anchor with id `link1`. I think you are looking for this.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var myHTML = "<div id='test'>";
            myHTML += "<a id='link1'>link 1</a>";
            myHTML += "<a id='link2'>link 2</a>";
            myHTML += "</div>";
            $("#insertHere").html(myHTML);
     });
```

You can use `after` to insert element after the element on which you called `after` method.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method to add html to a div that already exists is to use

```
$("div#insertHere").append(someHML);
```

each time this is called more code will be added to the element.

Try to reduce DOM manipulation (store as much HTML as possible before appending) so as to reduce load times.

Example:

```
$("div#insertHere").append("<div id='test'></div>");
$("div#test").append("<span><a id='link1'>link 1</a></span>");
$("div#test").append("<span><a id='link2'>link 2</a></span>");
```